# HTML Validator giving me error on form input type, element not allowed in context

Tags: html, w3c-validation

This is the code I have that HTML Validator is giving me an error on:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="keywords" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Submit" />
```

**Here is a screen shot of error in HTML Validator** ([full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B67V.png)):

[image: Screen shot of error in HTML Validator.]

This is the error message I am receiving:

> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> There are 2 types of elements in the body of a HTML file, inline and block elements. One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
>
> In the following sample, the <font> tag is an inline tag which can only contain other inline tags. But the <p> tag is a block tag. So a <p> tag can not be contained in a <font> tag.

This is the block of html that it is from:

```
<li>
    <form method="post" action="http://site.com/"  >
    <div class='hiddenFields'>
        <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="19" />
        <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="90ee0994104d8ba87b6ef9b43e998fc8c89e0d9f" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RP" value="search/results" />
        <input type="hidden" name="NRP" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RES" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="weblog" value="forms|alumni_distinguished|housing_faq|international_faq" />
        <input type="hidden" name="search_in" value="everywhere" />
        <input type="hidden" name="where" value="all" />
        <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="search" name="keywords" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" name="Submit" />
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In HTML4 / XHTML1, you can't put inline content directly into a `form` element. HTML5, on the other hand, lifts that requirement.

Thus, if the validation error bothers you (there are worse things...), add a `p` or `div` element around the last two `input`s.

Comment: Surprised this didn't get upvoted. This IS the correct answer. Inline elements are not allowed inside forms. So just enclose the input in a div to make validator happy.

Comment: Another point is that tables are allowed directly inside of a form. Since table make neither block-level nor inline elements, the validator obviously can't say "no" for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which HTML verion this validator validates against. Assuming that it is not XTHML, The input tag is not to be closed. The use of the "/>" implies that you are supplying a closing tag.

For more information : [Reference](http://htmlhelp.org/reference/html40/forms/input.html)

However, this restriction would not hold for XHTML which requires that all tags be closed. (or maybe I should say that the restriction that all tags should be closed applies only in XHTML) ;-)

Comment: In XHTML, it is used for tags that do not require a closing tag (img, input, etc).

Comment: Yes, I added that note as an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the inputs are in a `<li>` element, which by default is not a [block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3).  This is usually the cause of such 'out-of-context' errors.  It won't hurt your page at all, but just keep it from validating.

Comment: really ? I've always thought that li is a block level element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTML or XHTML

> In HTML the `<input>` tag has no end
>   tag.
>
> In XHTML the `<input>` tag must be
>   properly closed.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is there an unclosed inline element before the code you supplied? List of inline elements: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html (for html4)

Answer (score 0):

eg.
[code]

[/code]

wrap the input tag within a

tag

and be sure to self close the input tag like above.

This should validate.

Mark